# Visual Studio 2010 Express installation. Error 1935

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2010 Express. I got error 1935 during installation process. I tried many workarounds but still cant install it. I don't want to reinstall windows. Could some one help me?

Error messages:

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2908.

Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ManagedInterfaces.WCF,version="9.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="9.0.21022.8",culture="neutral"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x8002802F.

OS: Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Have you got the full error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a look the post on Joy Bhattacherjee's blog, which describes fixing error 1935?

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joy/microsoft-visual-studio-2010-ultimate-enu-error-1935-an-error-occurred-during-the-installation-of-assembly)

UPDATE

Have you tried installing it from a different location?  Specifically installing it from your local hard drive?

UPDATE 2

Try repairing the highest level of the .Net Framework on your PC.  If that doesn't work, you might want to check that your registry setting are ok ([http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/06/12/3260076.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012012319/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/06/12/3260076.aspx))

UPDATE 3

It might be down to something else you have installed.  Do you have other versions of Visual Studio? Ever installed any VS2010 betas?  Something to uninstall or reinstall.

UPDATE 4

Have you tried using the web installer? http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/#2010-Web-Platform-Installer .
You could also try one of the trial versions instead of the Express version. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/download , that might clean up the problem for the future.

Comment: I also tried this. I tried to reinstall and repair .net 4. I checked registry too :)

Comment: I surrendered :) I reinstalled windows and now all is ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with two steps:

1. Execute this command: sfc /scannow

This will search for errors in registry and repair them.

1. Increase the maximum size of the registry in this key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control 
Key: RegistrySizeLimit 
Type: REG_DWORD 
Value: 0xffffff (4294967295)

This solution was taken from: http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?t=287391&f=1148&c=93

Hope it helps!